# SSIS: Unable to write to Excel file (.xlsx) after copying the file using File System Task

Tags: excel, ssis

With my current scenario, I am implementing a functionality which reads data from SQL database and writes to excel file.

**File System Task Component:**
The destination excel file to which I am trying to write to is being copied in to destination directory from other source directory. The source directory has an excel file which I use as a template to copy it in to destination directory. For that I am using `"File System Task"` component and `"Copy File"` feature.

**ISSUE:**
The "File System Task" copies the file successfully but later the write to excel file fails with below error.

```
Opening a rowset for "C:\Users\Public\Documents\New_Carriers-2019-07-11.xlsx" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
```

**WORKAROUND / TROUBLESHOOTING:**
1. I set the project to `32 bit runtime` based on other users feeback.
2. I also applied delay prior actually start writing to file.
3. I also checked appropriate access rights to write file to destination directory.

Below is the screenshot of my control flow.

[image: Control Flow Task]

[image: File Sytem Task Editor]

[image]

Any direction towards the resolution is appreciated. There are similar post with same errors I found but I wonder why my issue looks different.

Comment: Im not sure whether because of that, I remember previous I also hit similar issue, when we copy excel to user folder, file is been opened and can't access, so maybe u can take a look for task monitor, and see whether have excel process after copy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run an Execute SQL Task to create the table/sheet in the Excel file, even if the file already exists.

[image: Execute SQL Task]

If you add this step after the File System Task, and parameterize your Excel connection properly it should allow you to insert data in the data flow.

Comment: Interesting, but hard to believe. Reason 1 - My destination excel file is not having static name. I concatenate date and time while creating it. How would I map that in CREATE TABLE query? Reason 2 - I had an experience with this functionality that after successful file creation, I was able to write data without writing such Execute SQL script.

Comment: The CREATE TABLE command isn't creating the file. You're creating a table within the file.  So if the file already has a table, you're good.  If you are creating a new file, you need to also create the table within the file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be one of the answer to such question as I found various scenarios pointing towards resolution to this kind of question. Hence, I am posting my triage which helped me overcome this issue.

I checked below things:

1. First, I checked `Task Manager` to see if any existing `Microsoft Excel` related process holding my files up. Which was not the case. (I.e. no existing process I found)
2. Second, I applied below steps to triage.
   2.1. I removed all previous files from the destination directory where I write new 
       files to make sure I am running my batch process afresh.
   2.2. I cleared everything from `%temp%` directory. (Which I believe might/might not
       be case for everyone)
   2.3. After performing above steps, I noticed in SSIS `Excel Destination component` 
       where we provide `Name of the Excel sheet` the component automatically adapted 
       the file name with `$` as suffix to indicate that the component has successfully
       established the connection with desired path to read the source template.
       For ex. my file name was `New_Carriers.xlsx`, the component has adapted the name
       as `New_Carriers$`.
   2.4. After that making these things I have been running my package till now without 
       any issue.
   Although, it might be straight forward, but took quite long to triage and confirm how to handle `Excel Destination` smoothly.